# How to create this type of index.php ? (Sitemap ?)

Tags: php, javascript, html, sitemap

I have a folder with tons of .html files

My folder is root/searches

Now i have tons of files in "searches" folder as "root/searches/example.html".I want to create an index.html for this folder as "root/searches/index.html"

Now in this index.html

I want to hyper link all the files in this folder . Basically like a sitemap.

NOTE: New files are created each second in this folder.So i can't do it manually.

This is my folder : http://www.searchr.us/web-search/

Can anyone give me the script or HTML for this ? 
Thanks

Comment: A decent tutorial here on the glob function
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/quick-tip-loop-through-folders-with-phps-glob/

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you are after?

```
$dir = '../dir';
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach($files as $file){
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..' || !is_file($dir.'/'.$file)){
        continue;
    }
    print "<a href=\"$file\">$file</a><br />";
}
```

This'll run through all of the files in the folder and print a link to them.

Comment: I'm getting a "500 Internal Server Error" when i use this :

Comment: <?php 
$dir = '../dir';
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach($files as $file){
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..' || !is_file($dir.'/'.$file)){
        continue;
    }
    print "<a href=\"$file\">$file</a><br />";
}
?>

Comment: Did you change 'dir' to 'web-search' - sorry I used 'dir' as an example!

Comment: <?php 
$dir = 'http://searchr.us/web-search/';
$files = scandir($dir);

foreach($files as $file){
    if($file == '.' || $file == '..' || !is_file($dir.'/'.$file)){
        continue;
    }
    print "<a href=\"$file\">$file</a><br />";
}

?> Still the same problem..

Comment: Is the page that displays the files in the same directory as the files? If not then could you edit your post and add your file structure, please. Thanks!